# Is there a way to plot a single origin symbol at the origin in base R?

Tags: r, plot, radix

I am trying to plot a capital, italized *O* at the origin, but how do I plot in that area?

MWE:

```
par(mar = c(6, 6, 4, 3) + 0.1, mgp = c(4, 1, 0))
x <- c(0, 10)
y <- c(0, 10)
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", type = "n", ylab = "")
mtext(expression(y), 2, 4, las = 1)
axis(1, 0:10, c("", 1:10))
axis(2, 0:10, c("", 1:10), las = 1)
```

[image: Origin location]

Comment: Does it *have to be* base R ? :)

Comment: @tjebo I would really prefer that. But I would certainly upvote other solutions as well, as they might be useful to others.

Comment: cool. btw, small smart-ass comment: `x <- c(0, 10); y <- c(0, 10)` could be shortened to `x <- y <- 0:10`

Comment: `text(-0.5, -0.5, ~italic(O), cex=2, xpd=TRUE)`

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, you should turn that into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `R-base` try this:

```r
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", type = "n", ylab = "")
mtext(expression(italic('O')), side=1, line=0, at=0, adj = 1.5)
mtext(expression(y), 2, 4, las = 1)
axis(1, 0:10, c("", 1:10))
axis(2, 0:10, c("", 1:10), las = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comment - you were asking for a base R solution, but here a fairly straight forward solution with ggplot2. Not working often with expressions, so not so sure about the warning which is produced.

This might be one of the moments where base R plotting shows more elegance than ggplot, so I am quite curious for a base R solution as well.

The ggplot2 solution below is a bit unideal, because you'll need to manually adjust the position of the annotation. There might be a more programmatic way to figure out the position of the other labels, by digging into the grobs, but I guess this would be maybe a bit of overdoing.

```r
library(ggplot2)
x <- y <- 0:10
mydat <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(mydat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, NA), breaks = 1:10) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, NA), breaks = 1:10) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, NA), ylim = c(0, NA), clip = "off") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -.2, y = -.2, label = expression(italic("O"))) +
  theme_classic()
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this can be useful to the many ggplot users out there!